# Insert dynamic variable for xpath inside foreach

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

is it possible for xpath to take dynamic values inside a foreach;;

p.e 
i have try with the bellow code and i get: Trying to get property of non-object error

```
foreach ($srcov as $src) {
   $qCoverXml = $coverXml->xpath('//cover/code[.= "'.  $srcC->Code  .'" ]/parent::*');
   echo  $qCoverXml->name;
}
```

I'm doing something wrong;
thanks

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: yes, it is possible, that's all what you want to know?

Comment: ok. i m sorry i will try again :) i use the above code and i get Trying to get property of non-object error if instead i use this code outside the foreach loop it works just fine.

Comment: In wich line do you get that error? Maybe `$coverXml` `$srcC` are not an object. Or the `$qCoverXml` is not an object.

Comment: the error is for the last line of the foreach ($qCoverXml->name;) i ιφ ιuse this code outside the foreach loop it works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, quoting simplexml documentation for [xpath() method](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php):

> Returns an array of SimpleXMLElement objects or FALSE in case of an error.

So, there are 2 things you did wrong.

1. you should check for error-cases
2. you should treat result as array

it will look something like this:

```
foreach ($srcov as $src) {
    $qCoverXml = $coverXml->xpath('//cover/code[.= "'.  $srcC->Code  .'" ]/parent::*');

    if (false === $qCoverXml) {
        echo "ERROR: request for {$srcC->Code} failed somehow\n";
        continue;
    }

    if (count($qCoverXml) == 0) {
        echo "ERROR: request for {$srcC->Code} didn't return any elements\n";
        continue;
    }

    echo  $qCoverXml[0]->name."\n";
}
```

Comment: thank you JimiDini you are right i was not treat the result as ar array, now it's working like a charm, thank you